# how to put .json info into .js file

Tags: javascript, json, html

I have an `html5` banner created with `flash cc`. The platform I am using to display/run the ad does not accept `JSON` files. 
How do I take the info from the `JSON` and put it either into my `.html` or `.js` file so I can eliminate the `JSON` all together.

Comment: Try this: `var yourJSON='json'`

Comment: JSON is a subset of JavaScript, so you... just put it in the file.

Comment: This question is a bit broad to fit properly on stackoverflow. Is the json file static or created dynamically? Whave have you tried? Also, keep in mind that json stands for JavaScript Object Notation and hence can be parsed easily into an object/array. I also think this may be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: think of validating the correct answer @Dawn

Answer (score 0):

Assign the JSON data to a normal javascript variable inside of a `<script>` element in your HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

You have these two approaches:

**HMTL**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   var jsonContent = JSON.parse("{name: 'json content in html'}");
</script>
```

**javascript**

```
var jsonContent = JSON.parse("{name: 'json content in javascript file'}");
```

Comment: OR, the most sensible one: `var jsonContent = {name: 'json content in javascript file'};`

Comment: the point of having it in a variable is to be able to manipulate it, it will make sense to keep `JSON.parse()` @LeeTaylor

Comment: Who said it was a variable? Once it's inside jsonContent it is variable anyway...

Comment: Yes but a variable with type string while parsing it results in an object. That makes it easier to manipulate